# WordPress plugin update not showing on wp.org

Tags: plugins, wordpress.org

I have been maintaining this plugin since quite some time...

https://wordpress.org/plugins/pootle-page-builder/

But on releasing v5.1.0 update is not showing even after about 20 hours (at the time of writing this)... I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

**This is my trunk**

`readme.txt`
https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/pootle-page-builder/trunk/README.txt
(I have correct `Stable tag` specified)

**This is my tagged version 5.1.0**

`readme.txt`
https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/pootle-page-builder/tags/5.1.0/README.txt
(again correct `Stable tag` specified)

Main plugin file
https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/pootle-page-builder/tags/5.1.0/pootle-page-builder.php
(version correct here too `5.1.0`)

I don't see my changelog modifications here either...
https://wordpress.org/plugins/pootle-page-builder/

I just don't understand why it's not grabbing new version even after 20 hours! It generally works within an hour or so...

Can anyone let me know if I'm missing something..?

Comment: I see the version 5.1.0 now

Comment: Yeah, I did a new commit and it started working ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those having this problem...

It's really rare...
In most cases you will be missing something like `Stable Tag:` in your readme.txt file (it should be latest production-ready version).

You will also need to make sure, version is correct on your main plugin `.php` file header.

Also... version should be tagged to `tags/{your_version}` with `svn copy` for example, to tag version 5.2.0 from master we would want to do...

```
svn copy trunk tags/5.2.0
```

This should match `Stable tag:`

If al this is done and you have like waited for at least 10 hours... And still version ain't live (which is very rare), you can go ahead and do another commit with maybe just another line break to like ping WordPress again...
Do this only when everything above doesn't work and you have waited like 10 hours and do it only once because this is an expensive operation for wp.org servers...

Hope that helps (somebody).