# Plugin doesn't update it's version and code on WordPress.org

Tags: plugins, updates, plugin-repository

When I make changes into my code and change the version 1.00 to 1.1, and commit it to the SVN, nothing happens. Plugin doesn't show any new version on wordpress.org 
The Plugins stays where it was, with the version 1.00

How to fix this WORDPRESS UPDATE FREEZE Problem?

Comment: read also this discussion : https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/286034/wordpress-plugin-update-not-showing-on-wp-org

Answer (score 0):

You should contact WordPress.org support via email: plugins@wordpress.org. But, I had similar experience recently, and it turns out that problem was connected with invalid header information in the plugins mail PHP (I have added an extra line under the line with plugin name), and that caused the problem with the WordPress.org plugin parser. Recheck main plugin file and the readme file to make sure they are correct. If that doesn't help, contact their support.